# python: function to change a list

Tags: python, list, function

I wanted to define a function to change a list in python 2.

```
lis=[[1,2],[3,4,5]]

def zu(l):
    import copy
    lcop=copy.deepcopy(l)
    while True:
        for i in range(len(lcop)):
            lcop=copy.deepcopy(l)
            for k in range(len(l[i])):
            lcop[i].pop()
    l=copy.deepcopy(lcop)
        break
    print l
    return l


zu(lis)
print lis
```

But executing the above code just yields:

```
[[1, 2], []]
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

So the original list is changed only locally inside the function. But i wanted to return it changed. And yes, I am new to python.

Comment: Why all those copies?

Comment: They are necessary in the actual function I created. This is just a cut-down version to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *assign* the returned list to your variable:

```
lis = zu(lis)
```

You have very carefully *not* mutated the original list in your function (by copying the list and mutating the copy), hence the need for an assignment. Alternatively, modify your function so that it *does* mutate the argument list.

Answer (score 0):

```
lis=[[1,2],[3,4,5]]

def zu(l):
    import copy
    lcop=copy.deepcopy(l)
    while True:
        for i in range(len(lcop)):
            lcop=copy.deepcopy(l)
            for k in range(len(l[i])):
            lcop[i].pop()
    l=copy.deepcopy(lcop)
        break
    print l
    return l


lis = zu(lis) # Here is the changes
print lis
```

But list is mutable in python so if you wanna modify the original list, just access the list inside the function without making a copy of it then it will change the original list you have outside, too.

for example

```
lis=[1,2,3]
print lst # print [1,2,3]
def zu(l):
    l[0] = [5]
zu(lis)
print lis # print [5,2,3]
```